# Using generic as method parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem when using generic types. IDE show me following error:

```
Cannot select from a type variable
```

I think here problem with type erasure, but I think here exist some workaround...

My code:

```
class MyFactory {
  public Object getByClass(Class<?> clazz) {
     ..... 
  }
}


class<T> MyClass {
  private Object myObj = MyFactory.getByClass(T.class);  // HERE ERROR, `Cannot select from a type variable` 
  ...
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Because of type erasure, it's impossible to tell at runtime what `T.class` is supposed to refer to.

Comment: @millimoose The `Type` of `T` may not even be a `Class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `Class` object into the constructor.

```
private final Class<T> clazz;
private Object myObj
public MyClass(Class<T> clazz, MyFactory myFactory) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.myObj = myFactory.getByClass(clazz);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that read:
this.myObj = myFactory.getByClass(clazz); 

Also, I don't think it's necessary to pass on the myFactory instance.

Comment: @JeroenWarmerdam Yup, fixed.

Comment: @JeroenWarmerdam (I mean I fixed the `T.class` to `clazz`. In the question `getByClass` is declared as an instance method. If it wasn't an instance method, then that would tend to suggest global state (a bad thing).)

Comment: I was reading the lower class in which the method is invoked statically. I see now that the upper class defines an instance method. I'll remove my example.